# I can't navigate to another page on the web browser by clicking on

Tags: c#

```
private void webBrowser1_Document(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)`
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;//Выключаем таймер, включенный по окончании загрузки страницы
    HtmlElement ListVer = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("SubmitButton");
    // Кнопка ОК
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("SubmitButton").InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

Clicking on this button should be a transition to another page. To use a url is impossible, because switch the page without changing the address bar

Comment: if you dont want the address bar to change but you want to swap urls?

Comment: In the program there is a link to the page in the browser. When switching from forms to form in the webBrowser address bar does not change. Change only the shapes themselves